# Change Color of Dygraphs Series Partway Through

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

In my dygraphs chart, I have a series which has been extrapolated.  I would like to color the extrapolated parts differently, but have not found a way to do that.

I suspect a way does not exist (since what I found in the documentation suggests color is per-series only), but in case there is a way, **how can I change the color of a data series partway through?**

Comment: Could you please provide jsFiddle or something with your actual chart?

Comment: @PetrShevtsov Not applicable, since my problem is getting dygraphs to do something--not the use of my data. An implementation in any of the [example (line) charts](http://dygraphs.com/gallery/) dygraph provides would be just as helpful to me.

Comment: So, do you want something like highlighted region (http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/highlighted-region) but just with different line color, right?

Comment: @PetrShevtsov yes.

Comment: Similar to this question, which is about changing a series from solid to dashed halfway through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006633/dygraphs-highlight-two-series-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 2):

You're quite right — there is no way to change the color of a part of a data series in Dygraphs. But it could be done using a separate series for extrapolated data like the following:

```
[
  [1, 0, null],
  [2, 2, null],
  [3, 4, null],
  [4, 6, 6],
  [5, null, 8],
  [6, null, 10],
  [7, null, 12],
  [8, null, 14],
]
```

```js
var g = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("g"), [
    [1, 0, null],
    [2, 2, null],
    [3, 4, null],
    [4, 6, 6],
    [5, null, 8],
    [6, null, 10],
    [7, null, 12],
    [8, null, 14],
  ], {
    colors: ['green', 'red'],
    labels: ['x', 'normal', 'extrapolated'],
    strokeWidth: 3,
    title: 'different series for extrapolated data'
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-dev.js"></script>
<div id="g"></div>
```